# How to define dynamic constructor in C++?

Tags: c++

It allocates memory to the objects while creating to sane memory space.
but how to define the dynamic constructor.

plz explain with an example.

Thanks.

Comment: Makes no sense to me. Please clarify.

Comment: i understood theoretically what is dynamic constructor but programmatically how to implement the constructor,i am unable to understand.

Comment: Well, have a bash and post some code when you hit a problem. One problem is that we don't know what you mean by a "dynamic constructor".

Comment: i don't know how to define it,then how come i'll write the prog??that is why i asked the question!!!

Comment: Tell us the source where you read about `dynamic constructor` or tell us your understanding about it, then we can know what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no *dynamic constructor* in C++. This is how to define a constructor for class A:

```
class A {
public:
    // Constructor
    A() { /* constructor code*/ }
};
```

This is how to allocate memory and construct the object:

```
A *a = new A();
```

Comment: thanks Juraj.i got my answer.

Comment: @Mahi: When you are satisfied with the answer you should accept it by clicking on the tick under the vote count.